# Как грамотно останавливать потоки Task в WinForms?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как грамотно остановить потоки Task в WinForms? Если к примеру использовать Wait то вызывающий поток блокируется, к примеру вызов из `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
Task[] th = new Task[ThreadCount];

parser parser = new parser();

for(int i = 0; i < th.Length; i++)
{
th[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => parser.s(parts[i], out_folder, mask)));
th[i].Wait();
}
```

блокирует всю форму, какими способами можно этого избежать?

Comment: Main является методом-исключением, который нельзя сделать асинхронным.
Причём тут WinForms? В какой момент сама форма запускается?

Comment: Сорри, неверно написал, исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте ключевое слово async на методе button1_Click:

```
private async void button1_Click...
```

Ожидание завершения Task через ключевое слово await, например, await th[i], в Вашем случае.

Comment: Дабы не создавать новую тему хотелось бы уточнить один момент - как я понимаю в примере:
1 поток запускается, выполняется, завершается. И только потом запускается 2 поток, пока второй поток не выполнится - 3 поток не запустится.
Вопрос - или у меня что-то не то с кодом, или Task не предназначена для одновременной работы нескольких потоков. 

Тогда какую либу посоветуете для синхронной работы потоков?

Comment: Несколько потоков именно "синхронно" выполнить не представляется возможным. Скорее тут подойдёт термин параллельно.
В Вашем случае можно, например, после цикла написать следующее:

    await Task.WhenAll(th);

Т.е. ожидание завершения всех запущенных потоков. Советую почитать по поводу исключений в самом MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh160374.aspx

Comment: Трудно сказать, что у Вас не так. Вот пример. На форме несколько Label и кнопка. Код следующий:

        private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            int delay = 1;
            foreach (Label lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
                {
                    await Task.Delay(delay++ * 1000);
                    lbl.Invoke(new Action(() => lbl.Text = "Поток завершил работу"));
                }));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }